# Update datetime when the link table is updated

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, last-modified

I have 2 tables, let's call it `computer_set` and `item_info`.

This is the `computer_set` sample data, as you can it has the `name` and description` of the set of computers

[image]

The table above is linked to `item_info` table via `cartTemplateNameID`column as you can see below.

[image]

My question is I would like to update the `lastModified` row on `computer_set` table whenever I updated any information in `item_info`. For example, if I add another item in `item_info` and `linked` it to `computer_set` it will automatically update the `lastModified` column of `computer_set` because a new item has been added to the group.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use MySQL [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: This is great, could you help me how to do that by giving sample queriy please?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to update lastModified after save item_info table data
Eg:-

```
<?php
/* your code */
$item_info->save();
$computer_set->save(['lastModified'=>date("Y-m-d h:i:s")]);
?>
```

or use mysql trigger. see attached image for phpmyadmin trigger example.
[phpmyadmin_trigger.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e7T8.jpg)

Thanks.